# How to give higher precedence to "Disabled" property instead of *ngIf to a button in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to disable or show or hide a button based on 2 conditions. Here is the logic which I am trying to achieve :

`if(condition1 === true){ disable the button } else { if(condition2 === true){ Hide the button } else { Show the button } }`

`

I want to achive this in HTML only and not in the ts and this is what I have tried in the HTML div:

```
<button *ngIf="condition1 && condition2"
 [disabled]="condition1"
 (click)="buyIt(orderD)">
 But it now
</button>
```

This does not seem to work as I need to show the button in disabled state if condition1 is true. Any help?`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition2">
     <button [hidden]="condition1">Buy it now</button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The condition you write is subjective.

Comment: Thanks for help but if condition2 is false, the button will not be visible. As mentioned condition2 should kick in only if condition1 is false.